# using opencv waitKey() in a multithreading application

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv, openni

I have a multi-threading application written in C++ with Qt5.7 and OpenNI. It has a main thread that starts a second thread which capture frame from a .oni recording file (asus xtion pro live) does some processing and through the Qt signal-slot mechanism pass the frame to the main thread, which display it using `imshow()`.
What I want to do is to implement a pause key, so pressing for example 'p' the processing pause. I am thinking of something like this:

```
void Camera::run(){
  while(!cameraStop && this->device.isValid())
    {
      try {
        if (!buttonPause) {
            getFrame();
            process();
            emit sigFrameImageReady(frame);
            if (cv::waitKey(1)==112){
              setButtonPause(!(getButtonPause()));
            }
          }

      }
      catch(std::exception &ex) {
        std::cerr << "getFrame()" << ex.what() << std::endl;
      }
    }
}
```

In this way it doesn't work, I think that's because the frame is displayed by another thread (the main one), the `waitKey()` here simply blocks the entire process, but if I put it in the main thread, just after `imshow()` in this way:

```
void Process::FrameImageReady(cv::Mat FrameImage)
{
  if (modedebug)
    cv::imshow("bgr", FrameImage);
  if (cv::waitKey(1)==112){
    cam->setButtonPause(!(getButtonPause()));
  }
}
```

waitkey seems to be ignored (image displaying works fine).. any idea?

*EDIT*
The GUI part is only for debugging purpose.

Comment: `imshow`, `waitKey` and other functionalities in `highgui` are meant for debugging purposes only. Since you're already using Qt, I suggest to show the images trough Qt functionalities which will behave correctly with threads

Comment: the image displaying works fine right now, the only problem I have is with waitkey(). Do you suggest to use a Qt function with same functionalities? Could you suggest one?

Comment: Check [KeyEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html), but it's not really my thing... I'm just suggesting to use Qt for all GUI stuff, since OpenCV functionalities are not meant to be used for complex tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement thread safe FIFO bufer or circular buffer in your displaying thread. Signal from the camera thread would be pushing images to this buffer and the displaying thread would be taking them out and display them in a separate loop. Only that way you separate the camera event loop from the display thread.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a late answer but I would like to present what I have done in my recent project, in case anyone is in the similar situation and want to use the same techniques.

Basically my project is a command line program and uses QT for multi threading & inter-thread communications, while we also want some minimal UI to display images, and handle user key events, so OpenCV Highgui module is pretty much enough for me. And here is what I did to make them work together:

1. **(Important)** you have to build OpenCV with QT support to make the
   following code work, that is, check `WITH_QT` option in cmake-gui when building OpenCV. Or if you use vcpkg, use:

   ```
   vcpkg install opencv[qt]:x64-windows
   ```
2. First create the class for working thread, I use this thread to constantly retrieve image frames from the camera buffer and notify the main thread every time the image is ready:

   ```cpp
   class MyThread : public QThread
   {
       Q_OBJECT

   public:
       MyThread() : mAbort(false)
       {
       }

       ~MyThread()
       {
           mMutex.lock();
           mAbort = true; // make the thread out of the loop
           mMutex.unlock();

           wait(); // wait until the run() function returns
           cout << "thread terminated" << endl;
       }

   protected:
       void run() override 
       {
           while(!mAbort) {
               cv::Mat frame;
               if (myCamera->grab(frame) && !frame.empty()) {
                   emit imageReady(frame);
               }
               else {
                   cout << "failed to grab" << endl;
               }
           }
       }

   signals:
       void imageReady(const cv::Mat& frame);

   private:
       bool mAbort;
       QMutex mMutex;
   };
   ```
3. Then create the controller class to handle the signal from working thread, I use it to display the frame. Note it is running in the main thread:

   ```cpp
   class MyController : public QObject
   {
       Q_OBJECT

   public:
       MyController(MyThread* pThread) : mThread(pThread)
       {
           // this is needed as the argument is passed through queued connection
           qRegisterMetaType<cv::Mat>("CvMat");
           connect(mThread, &MyThread::imageReady, this, &MyController::onImageReady);
           connect(mThread, &MyThread::finished, mThread, &QObject::deleteLater);

           mThread->start();
       }

   public slots:
       void onImageReady(const cv::Mat& frame) {
           cv::imshow("camera live view", frame);
       }

   private:
       MyThread* mThread;
   };
   ```
4. Now in the main function, we can start the thread, and handle key events using `cv::waitKey()`, note it will also start the QT main event loop internally.

   ```cpp
   Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(cv::Mat)
   ...
   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       ...
       // start working thread
       MyThread thread = new MyThread();
       MyController controller(thread);

       // handle key events
       while (true) {
           int key = cv::waitKey();
           cout << "key = " << key << endl;

           // press "ESC" to exit
           if (key == 27) {
               break;
           }
       }

       // clean up
       ...
       delete thread;
       delete myCamera;
       return 0;
   }
   ```