# Handle OpenCV waitKey() in multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I am trying to mess around with multi-threading and OpenCV so I wrote the following program.

```
void performSearch(Mat& original, Mat& grey, Mat& result)
{
    for(size_t index = 0; index < container.size(); ++index)
    {
         // do stuff

         imshow("Results", result);
         waitKey();
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread(performSearch, ref(image), ref(image_grey), ref(answer)).join();
    thread(performSearch, ref(image2), ref(image2_grey), ref(answer2)).join();
}
```

This program will throw an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` exception because `waitKey()` needs to be run on the main thread. My question is, how do I *attach* it to the main thread?

I have an iOS background and with grand central dispatch, I'd simply have to do something along the lines of:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async // this gets me the main queue asynchronously
{
    // update UI
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this in C++? If yes, how?

**Heads Up:**
I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700877/using-opencv-waitkey-in-a-multithreading-application) question and they're using QT for their GUI. I'm not.

Comment: Your `main` is running on the main thread. However all it does now is sit there waiting for the thread to finish. | What is it you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @DanMašek I need to run `performSearch` on two different images simultaneously and step through each iteration's result. See my updated question

Comment: Actually, after posting my answer and before your edit, I am not quite sure what the purpose of waitKey is inside your loop.

Comment: @Pruthvikar `waitKey()` allows me to visualize the results of my image operations after each iteration. Without it, it'd just run all `container.size()` iterations at once without visualizing them. I have `imshow()` calls in there as well.

Comment: @DanMašek What would u recommend I do then to achieve my task? `performSearch` needs to be run on both images simultaneously.

Comment: Something [like this](https://pastebin.com/urytJJJi)? Or you could even use `std::async` instead, I suppose.

Comment: Makes a bit more sense now. One option would be to use shared memory as shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595760/c-communication-between-threads

So you would poll for available results as they get added to a shared vector and then display them. That way the search carries on whilst waiting to show results.

Comment: @Pruthvikar Yeah, but it seems to me OP wants to display and wait, before proceeding to search 2 more images in parallel. Otherwise I'd say use some synchronized queues [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140643/how-to-save-two-cameras-data-but-not-influence-their-picture-acquire-speed/37146523#37146523) (of course with some modifications)

Comment: Ah, OP can you confirm if you want the search to pause when a result is found? Doesn't seem like that would make sense

Comment: I do want to pause when the result is found. That's why I kept the `waitKey()` inside the for loop.

Comment: use a "conditional wait" in the main thread that waits until your thread has perforned the imshow and a conditional wait in the worker thread that waits until the waitKey (that's executed in the main thread after the conditional wait) has finished.